# Why I can't install Debian 10 in dual boot alongside with Windows 10 (bitlocker enabled)?

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, debian, bitlocker

As the title says, currently I'm trying to install Debian 10 in a dual boot configuration alongside with Windows 10 (this is in my personal laptop).

With my previous laptops I didn't had any troubles going through this process (disabling secure boot, booting from the Debian USB, installing and then booting from GRUB giving the option to choose what OS to boot).

But the one that I bought last year is giving me trouble. When I loaded the Debian USB boot, started the setup. Everything normal until the disk partition part came. The installer could not detect the free partition that I made with Windows Disk Management (~ 70 GB). Disabled secure boot and tried again, the same. But instead, when I tried to boot on Windows now it booted directly on a BitLocker screen asking to put my encription key which I never before set up.

Got in panic mode and rollbacked everything to it's original config. After some reading before I write this I discovered that now Windows uses BitLocker to enhance the security features to prevent firmware-level changes and, in case of change, deny some actions and enter in a kind of "restricted mode". Now, this can be done with a TPM (which I guess my laptop is using) or by using the BitLocker encryption key which is set up by ourselves.

Considering that, my questions are:

- do I have to disable bitlocker to proper install Debian alongside with Windows 10 (w/ secure boot disabled)?
- How this will change the proper setup of the PC?
- Will I have trouble then with the TPM module when using Debian and then going back to Windows and viceversa?

Comment: BitLocker doesn’t require secure boot but if you disable secure boot you will have to provide the recovery key.  What edition of Windows 10 are you using exactly?  You will be unable to use a TPM to store your BitLocker key if you disable Secure Boot.  You will need to disable BitLocker protection in order to install Debian.  Only after it’s installed can you enable BitLocker.  This will of course make the Windows volume inaccessible on Debian.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm using Windows 10 Pro. I disabled BitLocker maintaining secure boot enabled and everything works good. The other thing I realized about is that, because of my SSD Driver in BIOS (they are in RAID On mode, instead of AHCI), the Debian installer can't see the free space that I made using Disk Manager so I will be working on that. Thanks for the response !!

Comment: Title of your question specifically says BitLocker protection is enabled. Secure Boot is independent of BitLocker